# Newline characters and StringIO

Tags: python

I'm pulling in data using urllib (Python 3) that arrives looking like this:

```
b'\n  9 27  70.40 43.40  0.00  15.90   3218.5    \n  9 28  74.90 43.70  0.00  18.30   3236.8'
```

Converting this to string it ends up like this:

```
"\\n  9 27  70.40 43.40  0.00  15.90   3218.5    \\n  9 28  74.90 43.70  0.00  18.30   3236.8"
```

I'd like to use numpy.genfromtxt to build an array, but I can't get io.StringIO to parse the newline characters. When I use:

```
table = io.StringIO(match.group(1), newline=r"\\n")  # or newline=r"\n"
```

I get an error message:

```
ValueError: illegal newline value: '\\\\n'
```

I've also tried keeping the data in the native bytes format and using io.BytesIO but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.genfromtxt(StringIO(b.decode() ))
```

The issue is probably with how you convert from bytes to string.

The output is:

```
array([[   9. ,   27. ,   70.4,   43.4,    0. ,   15.9, 3218.5],
       [   9. ,   28. ,   74.9,   43.7,    0. ,   18.3, 3236.8]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong method to convert bytes to string. `b'\n'` should convert to `'\n'` (assuming an ASCII-compatible encoding).

The correct way is with [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode), for example:

```
>>> b'\n'.decode()
'\n'
```

For more details see [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/606191/4518341), though it also covers Python 2, which has a wildly different approach to binary data.